# how to give dynamic border radius to custom widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am creating custom widget like rounded container where i want to make some properties dynamic like
height width and many others
as well as want dynamic border radius so that user can set it based on its requirenment...
like radius to all or only left or right like that

like

```
return  Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          child: RoundedContainer(
            applyRadius: true,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade100,
            showBorder: true,
            borderColor: Colors.red,
            child: const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                Text('A'),Text('B'),Text('C')
              ],),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

here is my reusable custom widget

```
class RoundedContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget? child;
  final double? width,height;
  final  Color backgroundColor;
  final bool showBorder;
  final bool applyRadius;
  final Color borderColor;
  final BorderRadiusGeometry? borderRadius;
   final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding;
  final BorderRadiusGeometry radius;


  const RoundedContainer({Key? key,
    this.borderRadius=BorderRadius.circular(12) ,//this statement showing error
    this.borderColor=Colors.blue,this.applyRadius=true,this.padding=const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),this.showBorder=false,this.backgroundColor=Colors.grey,this.child,this.width,this.height}) : super(key: key);

  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(

      width: width,
      height: height,
      padding: padding,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: backgroundColor,
        borderRadius:applyRadius? BorderRadius.circular(20):null,
        border: showBorder?Border.all(color: borderColor, width: 1):null,
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BorderRadius.circular` isn't a const constructor, therefore you can't use it as optional param. While it is already nullable,  you can use default value on null case,

```dart
 const RoundedContainer({
    Key? key,
    this.borderRadius,
```

```dart
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: borderRadius ?? BorderRadius.circular(20),
```

Now if you like to pass null which is zero border radius, you can pass `BorderRadius.zero` while using the widget.

Comment: sorry I am not sure about it

Comment: u have 58K..wow..must be expert in all code of flutter..i am here for 1 years and not getting well and trying...i have left all my jobs and gone learning for 1 years...dont know how will i get work or job.......dreams are not big but 30k

Comment: Nah, I am not that expert, just keep doing flutter as a hobby